# Which is better to send notifications, a python loop/timer, or as a cron job?

Tags: python, linux, loops, cron, raspberry-pi3

I've built a notification system w/ raspberry pi which checks a Database every two minutes, and if any new entries are found, it sends out emails. I have it working two ways..

1. A python script starts at boot and runs forever. It has a timer built into the loop. Every two minutes, the DB is checked and emails are sent.
2. A python script is set to check DB and send emails. A cron job is set to run this script every two minutes.

which would be the better choice and why?

Comment: Just use cron..

Comment: I'm partial to running the script as a service, as then you can easily log errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first option, even if you use a `sleep` implements a kind of **busy-waiting** strategy
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting),
this stragegy uses more CPU/memory than your second option (the cron approach) 
because you will have in memory your processus footprint 
even if it is actually doing nothing.

On the other hand, in the cron approach your processus will **only appear while doing useful activities.**

Just Imagine if you implement this kind of approach 
for many programs running on your machine, 
a lot of memory will be consume by processus in waiting states, 
it will also have an impact (memory/CPU usage) on the scheduling algorithm of your OS 
since it will have more processes in queue to manage.

Therefore, I would absolutely **recommend the cron/scheduling approach**.

Anyway,your cron daemon will be running in background whether you add the entry or not in the crontab, so why not adding it?

Last but not least, imagine if your busy-waiting processus is killed for any reason, if you go for the first option you will need to restart it manually and you might lose a couple of monitoring entries.

Hope it helps you.